# submitting a form without submit button

Tags: struts, struct

I am new to structs... I has an application in that there is drop down list with in a form like this..

```
 <%@taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld" prefix="prefix1" %>
<prefix1:form action="formaction">
  <prefix1:select property="choose">
    <prefix1:option value="1">1</prefix1:option>
    <prefix1:option value="2">2</prefix1:option>
    <prefix1:option value="3">3</prefix1:option>
    <prefix1:option value="4">4</prefix1:option>
</prefix1:select>
```

Now my problem is, i want to submit the form upon **onchange()** event instead of having a submit button. i.e, when ever a value from drop down list selected the form has to submit.. 
How can i do it??

Comment: you need a simple javascript to do the form submit onchange.

Comment: [Don't do that](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/navmenu.html)

Comment: @SKS: can i do that in struts also..?

Comment: Read Quentin article about submitting form onchange of drop down. If you still want to do it, then you can look at my answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** As mentioned in Quentin comment, you shouldn't submit your form onchange of drop down selection. [Read here](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/navmenu.html)

But if you still want to do it then, A simple javascript will do the trick, Provided javascript is allowed to use in your application.

1. Add a name to your form tag, `<prefix1:form action="formaction" styleId="formAction">`
2. Add below function inside `<script>` tag in your jsp
3. Add an onchange event handler to the select element, `<prefix1:select property="choose" onchange="submitForm()">`

> ```
>   function submitForm () {
>     document.getElementById("formAction").submit();
>   }
> ```

Comment: Its showing the error as... attribute name is invalid for tag form according to TLD and property attribute is not available for that also..

Comment: @user636207: My mistake, Just now looked at the tld definition here and seems like i have to use styleId as mentioned here http://struts.apache.org/1.x/struts-taglib/tlddoc/html/form.html

Answer (score 0):

I got my solution..Its looks like this

```
<prefix1:form action="sample">
 <prefix1:select property="choose" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <prefix1:option value="1">1</prefix1:option>
    <prefix1:option value="2">2</prefix1:option>
    <prefix1:option value="3">3</prefix1:option>
    <prefix1:option value="4">4</prefix1:option>
 </prefix1:select>
</prefix1:form>
```